# Does a recursive call reset to the beginning of the method if the call is in the middle?

Tags: recursion

Or does it finish the method? Sorry for noob question.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Can you give examples for the two options? Try to be more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive call is no different than any other call. Here is what happens when you call procedure X:

- The current address is pushed into the stack.
- Jump to the beginning of X.
- When X concludes, pop the return address from the stack, and jump there.

It doesn't matter whether X is the current procedure or a different one.

Comment: Note that the procedure might be different if X is called from X at the end of the subroutine, i.e. if X is tail-recursive.